# Cost function for word2vec

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I am currently doing text classification with pretrain by `word2vec`. But before feeding to `Convolution neural network`, I have to write cost function.

Here is my code:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocabulary_size, embedding_size]),
            trainable=False, name="W")

embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [vocabulary_size, embedding_size])
embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(embedding_init, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: final_embeddings})

embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, data)
embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(embedded_chars, -1)
```

the code for `word2vec` is [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py).

When I feed to the convex function:

```
filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
        embedding_init,
        W,
        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding="VALID",
        name="conv")
```

It gave me an following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9c12d490e7ab> in <module>()
     11             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
     12             padding="VALID",
---> 13             name="conv")
ValueError: Shape (50000, 128) must have rank 4
```

I suspect it is my tensor size is wrong but I am not really sure I to set it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is because the input vector to `tf.nn.conv2d` expects a tensor of shape:

```
[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
```

and what you have here is with shape (50000, 128). You might want to use `embedded_chars_expanded` as the input.

Comment: Thank , do the shape of input like this and I could work. `x = np.zeros((len(words1),len(dictionary)*embedding_size),dtype="float32")`. Is this a correct way ?

Comment: I misunderstood your code. You already get `embedded_chars_expanded`. Can you use that as the first argument in `conv2d` instead of `embedding_init`?

Comment: Thanks, Greeness. I have one more question I like too ask. I modify code of [dennybritz](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf) so It can run on pre-train word2vec. The training process working fine but the evaluation step crack my kernel (I use AWS m4.10xlarge instance type 16 gyte). My dictionary size is 2000 and embedding size is 128. I check my code many time but not sure why. Is the crack happens as the program use over memory ? I can post the code If you want to take a look. 
Thanks

Comment: yeah. I can take a look but no guarantees. :)  Are you running with Ubuntu 14.04 or above? Your embedding itself (2000 * 128 * 8bytes/doube = 2MB) that's very little memory.

Comment: I used "Amazon Linux AMI" as only this packer free with huge amount of memory. [word2vec + Training](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/Conv_Word2vec.ipynb). my [training data](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/2007ChallengeTrainData.xml) and my [CNN](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/text_cnn.py), Finally, my [load_data](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/load_data.py)

Comment: In which step of evaluation did your code crash? Can you point me to that file and related code?

Comment: [word2vec + Training](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/Conv_Word2vec.ipynb). At the for loop, end of the file, if you run that for loop. The kernel will crack when dev_step(x_dev, y_dev, writer=dev_summary_writer)`is running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124495/discussion-between-greeness-and-ngoduyvu).